# how can I avoid that this function executes as many times as the user press the button? - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making a todo app and don't know what is going bad on this. The user can push the button as many time as he want and I want only to function once. How can I do?

```
onTap: () {
    isComplet = !isComplet;
    if (Todo().isComplet = true) {
        DatabaseService().completTask(todos[index].uid);
    }
    if (Todo().isComplet = false) {
        DatabaseService().uncompletTask(todos[index].uid);
    }
},
```

I posted before the entire code. If it can help, here's the link to the other question. Thanks!

[How can I make that the on ttap button only be pressed one time? - Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67415959/how-can-i-make-that-the-on-ttap-button-only-be-pressed-one-time-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow, to execute the function only once, just have a `bool` variable and set it to false at the start of the widget, possibly in `initState()` or the `builder` function of `StreamBuilder` in case you are building multiple buttons in the same widget

`int _buttonPressedOnce = false;`

and modify your `onTap()` function a bit

```
   onTap: () {
      if (!_buttonPressedOnce) {
        _buttonPressedOnce = true;
        isComplet = !isComplet;
        if (Todo().isComplet = true) {
          DatabaseService().completTask(todos[index].uid);
        }
        if (Todo().isComplet = false) {
          DatabaseService().uncompletTask(todos[index].uid);
        }
      }
    },
```

Comment: It works but when I tried to "complet" other tasks that  I created, it doesnt allow me to mark them as completed. Why it can be?

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean by 'tried to "complet" other tasks" is your `onTap()` function not even executing once?

Comment: I have a list of tasks that are created on the todo app, but when I try to mark one as read, the other individual check buttons to press on their respective tasks, are disabled.

Comment: ok that's an easy fix, declare this `_buttonPressedOnce` inside your `builder` function under `StreamBuilder`

Answer (score 0):

There are two things.

1.) Denounce on Tap to prevent multiple tap:

```
          bool _isExecuting = false;
          void debounce(Function action) async {
            if (!_isExecuting) {
              _isExecuting = true;
              action();
              await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
                _isExecuting = false;
              });
            }
          }

     
          onTap: (){debounce((){
          // Your code
          })}
```

2.) Your Logic with tap:

```
onTap: flag ? () { True case function } : () { False case function },
```

Comment: what it flag means? sorry, im new to flutter

Comment: flag means any boolean variable

Answer (score 0):

This type of functionality isn't the best user experience in my point of view, you can use a loading spinner until the process finishes.
But if you want to do that as you said you can do something like below:

(You should use async programming if operations are asynchronous)

First of all, you should define a boolean called `tapped` or whatever you wanna call with a default value of `false`,

```
onTap: (){
    if(tapped) return;
    tapped = true;
    isComplet = !isComplet;
    if (Todo().isComplet = true)
    {DatabaseService().completTask(todos[index].uid);}
    if (Todo().isComplet = false)
    {DatabaseService().uncompletTask(todos[index].uid);}
    tapped = !tapped;
},
```